# DNS resolver keeps breaking

Tags: networking, server, dns

Every now and then, I'll try to ssh to something on my local network and I'll get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname pacman: No address associated with hostname
```

As soon as I restart the DNS resolver service `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` everything works...for a while until it eventually stops working after some time.

---

This only occurs on a single server (`zelda`). For the rest of the examples I'll be using `pacman` as the server I'm trying to connect to.

I'm running two local PiHole servers (`192.168.1.2` & `192.168.1.3`) with dnsmasq providing local name resolution. When running `systemd-resolve --status` I can see that both DNS servers are listed, including a valid currently connected server.

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.3
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.2
                      192.168.1.3
          DNS Domain: fakedomainforquestion.com
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (ens18)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

However when I try to lookup `pacman`'s DNS entry, I get nothing.
(This happens for other local hosts as well as other local FQDN's).

```
$ dig pacman

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> pacman
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 13374
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pacman.                IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 01 12:10:28 AEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 35
```

However querying the DNS server directly resolves just fine.

```
$ dig pacman @192.168.1.3

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> pacman @192.168.1.3
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27114
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pacman.                IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pacman.         0   IN  A   192.168.1.28

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.3#53(192.168.1.3)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 01 12:10:12 AEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

Furthermore, this only occurs on `zelda` specifically. `pacman` never has this issue, nor does any other device on the network. So it's safe to rule out the DNS server being problematic.

The DNS servers are not manually set per device, but instead are configured on the DHCP server for the entire network.

AFAIK the configuration on `zelda` is the same as the configuration on `pacman`. Both boxes are ~5 years old and have undergone LTS upgrades over their lives so maybe during an upgrade something may have caused `zelda` to deviate slightly.

While troubleshooting, I noticed that even when I restart `systemd-resolved`, the output of `dig pacman` is the exact same as when it does not work, yet I can now ssh into `pacman` just fine.